# Raspberry PI 3 fan doesn't work

Tags: pi-3, cooling

I have connected fan (5V, 0.2A) to raspberry pi 3 on pins 2 and 4. When I turn on raspberry, fan doesn't work. Does fan should start with turning on raspberry? Or I have to setup some configuration to get fan working?

Comment: Power is available on pins 2 and 4 while the Pi is powered.

Comment: @joan PI is powered, but fan doesn't work...

Comment: Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: I don't know, maybe fan is faulty. Or pins are faulty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the official pin diagram, pin 2 and 4 are both 5v.

[image]

Try to connect with pin 2 (5v) and pin 6 (ground).

Comment: Note that many 5V fans work with 3.3V, providing sufficient cooling while making far less noise. So it's worth a try to connect it to pins 1 and 6 as well.

Comment: Thank you @lara-maia. It sounds logical, I have red and black wires on fan. Can I also  connect pin 4 and pin 6?

Comment: @poletn23 Yes, pins 2 and 4 are interchangeable, so you can use 4 and 6.

Comment: That's it. It's working on pins 4 and 6. Thank you all.